# Tarski's caracterisation of inaccessible cardinals

Tags: set-theory

Alfred Tarski, in his paper "Ueber unerreichbare Kardinalzahlen" Fund. Math. vol 30 (1938) pp 68-89 proves the followig theorem of ZFC  "If the cardinal of the set Y is equal to the cardinal of the set of the subsets of Y that are not equipotent with Y, then the cardinal of Y is (strongly) inaccessible".  The proof of the paper is rather long and involved.
Question: Is there another known simpler proof of this theorem ?
Gérard Lang

Comment: Are you sure you quoted the theorem correctly?  The continuum hypothesis implies that a set of size `$\aleph_1$` has only `$\aleph_1$` countable subsets.

Comment: I'm confused by the statement of the theorem. There are $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ many countable subsets of $\aleph_1$, assuming $CH$, so this would imply that $\omega_1$ is strongly inaccessible. What am I missing?

Comment: YES,I am VERY SORRY, I did not think "inaccessible", but "regular !!!
I will write the correct question;
Gérard lang

Comment: There is no need to write another question, it was already answered here.

Comment: Is Tarski using the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern notation, it says, "if $\kappa$ is a cardinal and $\kappa ^{< \kappa} = \kappa$, then $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible."  This isn't entirely true since the antecedent holds for $\kappa = \omega$ but $\omega$ isn't considered strongly inaccessible, but that's not a big deal.  More importantly, under CH the antecedent will hold of $\aleph _1$ but $\aleph _1$ isn't a limit cardinal.  So we need to add the assumptions that $\kappa$ is an uncountable limit cardinal.  Given that, we can proceed:

So let's assume $\kappa ^{< \kappa} = \kappa$.  First we show $\kappa$ is strong limit: $\kappa \leq 2^{< \kappa} \leq \kappa ^{< \kappa} = \kappa$.  Next we show $\kappa$ is regular: Suppose not, then $\kappa ^{< \kappa} = \kappa < \kappa ^{ \mathrm{cf} ( \kappa) } \leq \kappa ^{< \kappa}$, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much.
This is the right answer for my very question !
Gérard Lang