# Tarski's caracterisation of REGULAR cardinals

Tags: set-theory

Alfred Tarski, in his paper "Ueber unerreichbare Kardinalzahlen" Fund. Math. 1938 proves the following ZFC theorem "if the cardinal of the set Y is equal to the cardinal of the set of subsets of Y that are not equipotent to Y, then the cardinal of Y is REGULAR." The proof of the paper is rather long and involved.
Question: Is there another known simpler proof of this theorem ?
Gérard Lang

Comment: How many theorems with rather long and involved proofs did Tarski's paper contain?

Comment: This was already solved in the other question.

Comment: Which other question?


Comment: Oh I see, you mean http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52526/tarskis-caracterisation-of-inaccessible-cardinals

Comment: Hi Stefan, yes, I would have suggested to move your answer there but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me prove the contraposition:  If $\kappa$ is not regular, then it has more than $\kappa$ subsets of size strictly less than $\kappa$.

Suppose $\kappa$ is not regular.  Let $\lambda$ be the cofinality of $\kappa$.
Note that the number of subsets of $\kappa$ of size $\lambda$ is $\kappa^\lambda$.  It is therefore enough to show that $\kappa^\lambda$ is strictly larger than $\kappa$.

Choose a cofinal sequence $\{\alpha_\gamma:\gamma\in\lambda\}$ of ordinals in $\kappa$.
Let $f:\kappa\to{}^\lambda\kappa$ be a function.  We show that it is not onto.  Define $g:\lambda\to\kappa$ be letting $g(\gamma)$ be the least element of $\kappa\setminus\{(f(\beta)(\gamma):\beta\in\alpha_\gamma\}.$
This exists since $\{(f(\beta)(\gamma):\beta\in\alpha_\gamma\}$ is of size striclty less than $\kappa$.  Then $g$ does not appear in the range of $f$.

For suppose $g=f(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in\kappa$. Choose $\gamma\in\lambda$ such that $\alpha\in\alpha_\gamma$. Then $g(\gamma)\not\in\{f(\beta)(\gamma):\beta\in\alpha_\gamma\}$ and hence in particular, 
$g(\gamma)\not=f(\alpha)(\gamma)$, a contradiction.

This is, I believe, the usual proof of König's Theorem (not the tree-lemma) that you should find in any standard text book on set theory.